# Taking image from native camera without a sdcard

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I am trying to write a application which i will take image from camera and use it. At first i used

Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

However i noticed that this will just return thumbnail of the image. So i updated my code as:

```
public void takePhoto(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File dir = context.getDir("directory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File photo = new File(dir, "Pic.jpg");
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode){
            Uri selectedImage = mImageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap=android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                displayIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Problem is after upgrading the code it stopped calling onActivityResult function after i finish taking photo. 
After taking picture i am clicking  DONE button on camera screen but it doesnt call the application back. The app stays in camera screen.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Press the BACK button. There is no requirement for a camera application to immediately return control to your app.

Comment: BACK button just cancels the Camera. It doesn't call the onActivityResult function where i will use the image i took and also DONE button was calling the app back while i was reading thumbnail from data.

Comment: Try using a `File` that the camera app can write to, as it cannot write to your requested location. Use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`, for example. It may be that the camera app that you are using does not bother calling `setResult()` if it cannot write the image where you requested, and `setResult()` is what triggers `onActivityResult()` in your activity.

Comment: It wont work either because this app needs to work without external storage. I need a SD-card in order to use  getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalCacheDir()

Comment: "It wont work either because this app needs to work without external storage" -- all Android devices that legitimately ship with the Play Store have external storage, at least 1GB when the device ships from the factory. "I need a SD-card in order to use getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalCacheDir()" -- external storage, from the standpoint of the Android SDK, has not been an "SD-card" in years for most devices. Regardless, if you are going to use a third-party app to take the picture, the third-party app has to have write access to the directory where the image is to be stored.

Comment: In other words, don't use Context.MODE_PRIVATE.  However there's no guarantee that the camera app which opens to handle this will try to write to a internal storage location, even if it has permission to - some apps put in their own less than accurate *assummptions* about what they can and can't access.

Comment: Mine problem was little different than I thought. First of all @CommonsWare thank you for all your detailed explanations. I will give detailed explanation for the solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External storage write permissions needs to be add to manifest.